Is Pop Art and Mass-Produced Cinema Considered Art?
Exploring Definitions and Historical Perspectives
Recently, I had a discussion with a friend who argued that pop art (e.g., mass-produced cinema) and anything created for mass consumption, particularly by the working class (or for the working class/masses), should not be considered "true art." Their perspective seemed to stem from a belief that "art for art's sake" holds a higher value than art created with commercial or mass appeal. They also referenced historical and cultural distinctions between "high art" and "popular art."
This left me puzzled, as I view works like Star Wars and The Matrix as artistic masterpieces, encompassing innovative storytelling, groundbreaking technical achievements, and iconic musical scores. It raises several questions about how art is defined and valued:

How is art generally defined, and how do definitions vary across disciplines? For example, are there widely accepted criteria that distinguish "high art" from "pop art"?
What are the historical or cultural reasons behind the separation of "art for art's sake" and art made for mass consumption?
Have mass-produced works like Star Wars been recognized within academic or cultural institutions as art? Are there examples of similar works that have been embraced as art?

Some interesting quotes from our discussion were:

"Art that is not for art's sake - is not art."
"Anything mass produced to target the working class is not art".
"Mass art is for the average worker/(average person), not for the master of art (or appreciator of art)."

I’d appreciate fact-based insights, citations of historical or scholarly perspectives, and examples that can help clarify whether pop art and mass-produced cinema can and should be considered legitimate forms of art.

This seems to be a matter of one individual's personal definition of the term "real art". I see no particular reason to accept that definition as anything more than their own opinion. De gustibus non disputandum est.

It reminds me of people who feel the need to declare that the way other people are playing games are invalid. It's also not entirely unrelated to people declaring attraction to one gender instead of another is invalid. That wearing one colour instead of another is invalid. That playing with one toy instead of another is invalid. It's just people trying to impose their personal preference onto others under the pretence of an objective classification.

As long as you do not give your definition of "art" - which possibly is not an easy task - the whole debate hangs in the air and is just an exchange of personal opinions.

The core of this discussion boils down to the distinction between the terms 'artist' and 'artisan'. In short:

'Artist': A person involved in the crafting of strictly creative/expressive artifacts, ones that seeks to carry forward a story, narrative, ideal, impression, etc.
'Artisan': A person involved in crafting functional artifacts that demonstrate style, motif, elegance, attractiveness, etc.

Artistry is considered to be purely expressive, and is valued as much for its depth of meaning as the skill of its production. Artisanship is mainly commercial, the skilled production of ostensibly useful objects that beautify or enhance experience in a superficial or non-expressive form. Artistry usually produces one-of-a-kind items, after which the artist turns to express something new. Artisanship relies on a replicable aesthetic that can turn out quantities of near identical items.
The modern problems of art begin (at least archetypically) with Andy Warhol, who created his art using strong elements of 'mere' reproduction, blurring the distinction between the artist and the artisan. And this problem has only increased over time. While there is still art being made in the classic sense, every form of art can be digitized, reproduced, and distributed to mass markets for commercial purposes, and many mass-market commercial products are lionized as 'art' without any real analysis of their expressive depth. I mean sure, the original "Star Wars" movie was a technological marvel for the 1970s, but the story itself was typical YA fantasy without any real plot or character development. Compare that to (say) the slightly earlier and much less successful "Silent Running", which lacked that technological 'wow' factor but actually had some artistry in theme and characterization.
I dislike the somewhat Marxist conception that 'pop-art' is being sold to the 'working classes' (perhaps as a new opiate to replace religion). I don't disagree with the concept entirely, mind you, but I disagree with the suggestion that laborers are somehow more susceptible to this than the upper (or middle) crust. Everyone likes a good fantasy; everyone likes to escape from the petty doldrums of their lives for a moment. But I think there is a distinction to be made between 'pure' escapism (the "let's not think about crap for a while" aspect of things like "Star Wars") and proper expressionism (the "let's engage the problem for a moment" aspect of things like "Silent Running"). If we don't make that distinction, then 'art' is truly dead; reduced to a technological 'wow' factor where stimulation replaces inculcation.

great answer :) !!

I doubt many Star Wars fans would agree that it is merely a "typical YA fantasy without any real plot or character development" that's propped up by "a technological 'wow' factor". I'd be some surprised if someone even tries to make a case that there's little to no creative work on display in terms of, say, the worldbuilding, character design, tone setting, and acting in Star Wars. You have to be fairly careful in carving out your definition of "valid" creativity, and still lean heavily on opinion, to say that Star Wars isn't art.

If anything seems likely to kill art (or at least kneecap it), it would be gatekeeping of what is and isn't allowed to be called art, based on little more than personal opinion and subjective judgement, by people who like to think they're better than everyone else, who focus on degrading others and what they like, instead of respecting a diversity of opinion, and just promoting what they like, instead.

One has to wonder to which degree jealousy and the realisation of being well past losing the battle factors into this. Most of the highest grossing movies of all time are franchises that the artsy crowd tend to look down upon, and which they tend to consider far inferior to their intellectual artsy movies. Even fans of those franchises have gotten annoyed by studios pumping out sequel after sequel, and being more interested in profit than artistic value. So the artsy crowd adopt the extreme position of declaring that to not even be "art" at all, in a misguided attempt to gain support.

@NotThatGuy: First let me point out that your first comment is a perfect set up for a lot of jokes about Star Wars fans. But I'm using the force to hold those jokes back, so… you're welcome.

@NotThatGuy: Your second comment merely denies the possibility of philosophical aesthetics, and I'm not buying that. Art in whatever form it takes is always a form of communication, and not everyone is capable of communicating well in those forms.

@NotThatGuy: Don't think I'm against MCU productions. I like them; they're fun and entertaining. But I'm not to elevate them to artistry, any more than I'd call a compilation of Peanuts cartoon a graphic novel. MCU is good at what it does, but it isn't trying to communicate anything more sophisticated than oohs and ahh.

@TedWrigley "Your second comment merely denies the possibility of philosophical aesthetics" - no, I just reject the objectivity of your particular subjective judgement of "valid" aesthetics. I reject that there's a categorical difference in whether it's art, between big-budget movies that appeal to the masses, and artsy movies (there may often be a categorical difference in motivation of the producers - making money versus making art, but many of the artists they hire are still making art). I have no issue with people discussing subjective artistic value. I just don't see objectivity there.

@TedWrigley "not everyone is capable of communicating well in those forms" - I find a lot of artsy movies to be painfully boring and devoid of any subjective value (unlike non-artsy movies, which often evoke a wide range of desirable emotions). From my perspective, the creators of artsy movies aren't "communicating well". But I realise that this is just personal taste, and that different people find value in different things, I don't generally see much value in denigrating harmless things that give others joy. I'd recommend to the artsy intellectuals to try to show the same level of maturity.

@NotThatGuy: Well, I'm starting to find this conversation painfully boring and devoid of any subjective value, so I'm changing the channel. Have a good one!

You are looking for a degree of clarity that does not exist. Art is a vague term. What constitutes art is therefore partly a matter of convention and partly of opinion. You and your friend are equally entitled to take different views on the matter. You might as well look for the final word on whether Mozart is better than Madonna- it depends on whom you ask.

And why you ask, when you ask, for what purpose...  This is a multi-dimensional space, not a single axis.

@keshlam agreed. Nicely put.

Setting aside what is better, I'd argue that "art" is artificial, i.e. it is not what would come to be naturally but which is the result of skill and deliberation.
Now there is an obvious problem that humans are still part of nature and that what humans create artificially is almost inevitably natural or will become natural the moment other people incorporate it into their daily lives and make it part of their "nature".
In that sense you could argue that something produced for the masses is not art, as it fulfills a function (even if that function is just a token that everyone knows and is thus able to relate to). So it's more of a part of nature than of art. While things that art not seen and appreciated by others and that are obscure would be art.
Which creates the obvious problem that the best artist would be a struggling loner while the most consumed "artist" would be no artist at all. Also none of that would tell you anything about the skill of the person making the art or about the aesthetic value, it would just be about... idk novelty.

Re. How is art generally defined, and how do definitions vary across disciplines?
I'll just drop this in here for a different perspective.  It runs from art as existence, e.g. "Thou art.", to art as care: artfulness, art as fine art, and art as social change (the revaluation of values), art as the nisus of life, doing things artfully, with aplomb (which is rather what one appreciates in a commercial work of art).
Such a broad range, it makes the distinction between "high art" and "pop art" somewhat smaller, though I would say pop art and high art can be the same.
But to kick off, from Nietzsche's Will to Power 853 II:

Art and nothing else! Art is the great means of making life
possible, the great seducer to life, the great stimulus of life.

Nietzsche is not talking about fine art, or getting lost in a painting as per Schopenhauer.
To clarify somewhat, quoting from Heidegger's Nietzsche I: The Will to Power as Art, pages 70–72:

If we take the assertion in the guiding context of the question of
will to power, with a view to the essence of art, then we derive at
once two essential statements about art:

Art is the most perspicuous and familiar configuration of will to power;
Art must be grasped in terms of the artist.

And now let us read further (WM,
797):
" . . . from that position to scan the basic instincts of power, of
nature, etc.! Also of religion and morals!" Here Nietzsche says
explicitly that with a view toward the essence of the artist the other
configurations of will to power also—nature, religion, morals, and we
might add, society and individual, knowledge, science, and
philosophy—are to be observed. These kinds of beings hence correspond
in a certain way to the being of the artist, to artistic creativity,
and to being created. The remaining beings, which the artist does not
expressly bring forth, have the mode of Being that corresponds to what
the artist creates, the work of art. Evidence for such a thought we
find in the aphorism immediately preceding (WM,
796):
"The work of art, where it appears without artist, e.g., as body, as
organization (the Prussian officer corps, the Jesuit order). To what
extent the artist is only a preliminary stage. The world as a work of
art that gives birth to itself—." Here the concept of art and of the
work of art is obviously extended to every ability to bring forth and
to everything that is essentially brought forth. To a certain extent
that also corresponds to a usage that was common until the outset of
the nineteenth century. Up to that time art meant every kind of
ability to bring forth. Craftsmen, statesmen, and educators, as men
who brought something forth, were artists. Nature too was an artist, a
female artist. At that time art did not mean the current, narrow
concept, as applied to "fine art," which brings forth something
beautiful in its work.
However, Nietzsche now interprets that earlier, extended usage of art,
in which fine art is only one type among others, in such a way that
all bringing-forth is conceived as corresponding to fine art and to
the artist devoted to it. "The artist is only a preliminary stage"
means the artist in the narrower sense, one who brings forth works of
fine art. On that basis we can exhibit a third statement about art:

According to the expanded concept of artist, art is the basic occurrence of all beings; to the extent that they are, beings are
self-creating, created.

But we know that will to power is essentially a creating and
destroying. That the basic occurrence of beings is "art" suggests
nothing else than that it is will to power.
. . .
Art, thought in the broadest sense as the creative, constitutes the
basic character of beings. Accordingly, art in the narrower sense is
that activity in which creation emerges for itself and becomes most
perspicuous; it is not merely one configuration of will to power among
others but the supreme configuration. Will to power becomes
genuinely visible in terms of art and as art. . . . If will to power
therefore finds its supreme configuration in art, the positing of [a]
new relation of will to power must proceed from art. Since the new
valuation is a revaluation of the prior one, however, opposition and
upheaval arise from art.

